# Complex integration and Gauss mean value theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to show that $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log | 1-ae^{i\theta}|d\theta=0$ for $|a|<1$ implies
$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log | a-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=0$

Comment: If $|a|> 1$ it can be shown the integral you wrote is equal to $\log |a|$ by the Gauss MVT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint: $$|a - e^{i\theta}| = |a e^{i\theta}e^{-i \theta} - e^{i\theta}| = |a e^{-i\theta} -1|$$
and
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log| 1 - ae^{i \theta}| \, d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \log| 1 - ae^{-i \theta}| \, d\theta.$$

Comment: Thank you .... It was stupid easy and now I feel silly having asked.

Comment: It's even easier than that.  We have simply $$|1-ae^{i\theta}|=|a-e^{i\theta}|$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this is to note that for $a$ real valued we have

$$|1-ae^{i\theta}|=\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\cos \theta}$$

and

$$|a-e^{i\theta}|=\sqrt{1+a^2-2a\cos \theta}$$

---

Note that if $a$ is complex, then we have

$$|1-ae^{i\theta}|=\sqrt{1+|a|^2-2|a|\cos (\arg(a)+\theta)}$$

and

$$|a-e^{i\theta}|=\sqrt{1+|a|^2-2|a|\cos(\arg(a)- \theta)}$$

Exploiting the $2\pi$-periodicity and evenness of the cosine function, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} |a-e^{i\theta}|\,d\theta&=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+|a|^2-2|a|\cos(\arg(a)- \theta)}\,d\theta \tag 1\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+|a|^2-2|a|\cos(\arg(a)+ \theta)}\,d\theta \tag 2\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} |1-ae^{i\theta}|\,d\theta
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we enforced the substitution $\theta \to 2\pi-\theta$.

Comment: There is a typo in the second equality. But what if $a$ is complex?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes, thank you for the catch.  +1 for the comment.  If $a$ is complex, the generalization would be $|1-ae^{i\theta}|=\sqrt{1+|a|^2+2|a|\cos (\theta +\arg(a))}$.  And of course $|a-e^{i\theta}|=\sqrt{1+|a|^2+2|a|\cos (\arg(a)-\theta)}$.  Then, we have equivalence of the integrals by exploiting $2\pi$-periodicity and evenness of the cosine function ... similar to your development.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark